# Batch Script To Move Files With Multiple Scenarios

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have an automation process in place using batch files to moves a collection of 5 files 1 at a time into a specific order into a staging directory then perform an operation on that file prior to moving on to the next file.  The process is successful until a new scenario such as below occurs.

The new scenario is that randomly--usually Mondays--there are multiple occurrences of each of the 5 files (usually when this occurs there are 2 sets).  What I need to figure out is how to move them in the order--that the above described action-- so that the files in set 1 is moved one-at-a-time before moving set 2 files.

A sample of how these files are named is as follows:

Date that the sample list of files below were received was 20141028.

```
Set 1
file_asia1.txt.20141026
file_asia2.txt.20141026
file_euro.txt.20141024
file_lamr.txt.20141024
file_namr.txt.20141024

Set 2
file_asia1.txt.20141027
file_asia2.txt.20141027
file_euro.txt.20141026
file_lamr.txt.20141026
file_namr.txt.20141026
```

I need to move each file in set 1, then move on to set 2.  I have tried to research this and cannot find any instances with the above requirements are met.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure paths
    set "sourceFolder=c:\some\where"
    set "targetFolder=d:\other\somewhere"

    rem Configure the required files in the correct order
    set fileSet="file_asia1.txt" "file_asia2.txt" "file_euro.txt" "file_lamr.txt" "file_namr.txt"

:loop
    rem Check it there is a file for each defined element in the set. If not, leave 
    for %%a in (%fileSet%) do dir /b /a-d "%sourceFolder%\%%~a*" >nul 2>nul || goto :eof

    rem We have files, continue the process
    rem For each file in the set, find the first matching one and process it
    for %%a in (%fileSet%) do (
        set "first="
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('
            dir /b /a-d /on "%sourceFolder%\%%~a*"
        ') do if not defined first (
            set "first=1"
            echo processing %%~b
            move /y "%sourceFolder%\%%~b" "%targetFolder%" >nul
            rem Do what needs to be done
            rem ....
        )
    )

    rem Go test for another set of files
    goto :loop
```